# Magento Custom URL

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I've created a new module to replace the customer/account menu and has a link www.mysite.com/account

I now want to change the login, registration and other pages to show as www.mysite.com/account/login etc

instead of reverting back to customer/account/login etc

Whats the best way to do it?

Here is the config.xml code Ive made so far....

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <SquareNetMedia_MyAccount>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </SquareNetMedia_MyAccount>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <myaccount>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>SquareNetMedia_MyAccount</module>
            <frontName>account</frontName>
          </args>
      </myaccount>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <myaccount>
              <file>myaccount.xml</file>
            </myaccount>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>

    <helpers>
      <myaccount>
        <class>SquareNetMedia_MyAccount_Helper</class>
      </myaccount>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <myaccount>
        <class>SquareNetMedia_MyAccount_Block</class>
      </myaccount>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Magento uses following std url format: site.com/modulename/controller/action  if you want a different url format then try with magento rewrite or use some .htaccess rules

Answer (score 0):

Change your file to look like this:

```
 <frontend>
 <routers>
 <myaccount>
    <use>standard</use>
      <args>
        <module>SquareNetMedia_MyAccount</module>
        <frontName>account</frontName>
      </args>
  </myaccount>
  <customer>
    <args>
      <modules>
        <SquareNetMedia_MyAccount before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">SquareNetMedia_MyAccountr</SquareNetMedia_MyAccount>
      </modules>
    </args>
  </customer>
```

Then make a new controller file called AccountController.php in your module's controller folder

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php';
class SquareNetMedia_MyAccount_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{
}
```

now you can override the functions

```
 public function loginAction(){
 #Here you can do what you need I think
 }
```

I hope that's right, let me know if it wasn't clear. Peace.

Comment: Thanks - I've changed my code but now all I get is a 404 error

Instead of Account Controller.php I was using IndexController.php before and it loaded the new layout but now when you amend to the code above nothing works